# Array Search Algorithm

Tags: c++, algorithm, search, binary-search

Recently, I've been experimenting with an **array searching algorithm** that I'm not sure I've seen anywhere *(minor references [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/searching-algorithms/))*.

I'm still not fully-learned on how to state the efficiency of what I've done (as per writing it's speed in mathematical notation (e.g.: \$O(\log n)\$) either but I'd like to pass on that this **method** is most efficient when searching through **large non-sorted arrays**.

With the tests I've done in JavaScript (which I mainly use to program), it is faster than:

- Linear searching when the element is at the end of the array.
- Reversed linear searching when the element is at the start of the array.

---

This was the original code (but ported to C++):

```
/* Assert if an element is within an (int) array */
bool includes(int array[], int element, int length) {
    if (length == 1)
        return array[0] == element;

    else if (length) {
        int iterator = length,
            halfLength = (length / 2) >> 0, // Convert to integer.
            quarterLength = (halfLength / 2) >> 0,
            thirdQuarterLength = halfLength + quarterLength;

        // Do not iterate completely through the array
        while (iterator != thirdQuarterLength) {
            iterator -= 1;

            // Check four indexes at once.
            if (
                array[length - iterator - 1] == element ||
                (iterator - halfLength > -1 && array[iterator - halfLength] == element) ||
                (halfLength + (length - iterator - 1) < length) && (array[halfLength + (length - iterator - 1)] == element) ||
                array[iterator] == element
            ) return true;
        }

        return false;
    }

    else
        return false;
}
```

With this code:

- The iteration count of the loop is reduced four-fold.
- Four indexes of the array are queried each iteration of the loop (instead of 1 at a time).
- The algorithm's speed is not dependent on the element's location in the array (e.g.: Linear searching is slow if the element is at the end of the array).

Syntax-wise I would say this method tends toward writing `"Hello, World!"` four (or `x` depending on how it's scaled) times instead of using a repetition structure (e.g.: `for...` loop).

---

Now, this was all well and good, but I decided to go even further.

I asked what if could search more than (or less than) four indexes at once? The number of indexes queried each iteration specified by the user.

So I came up with this (again ported to C++):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

// Format each element of an (int) array.
void build(int array[], int length, int (&handler)(int element)) {
   int iterator = length;
   while (iterator) { iterator -= 1; array[iterator] = handler(array[iterator]); }
}

// Return a set of the multiples of Number ÷ Count lower than or equal to the Number.
int* step(int number, int count) {
    float difference = number / count;
    int* steps = (int*) malloc(20) /* This was an array literal in JavaScript but I think this counts... :P */;
    bool hasStepped = false;

    while (count) {
        steps[count -= 1] = (hasStepped ? steps[count + 1] : 0) + difference;
        hasStepped = true;
    }

     return steps;
}

/* Assert if an element is within an (int) array */
bool includes(int array[], int element, int length, int iterationStopCount = 4) {
    if (length == 1)
        return array[0] == element;

    else if (length) {
        int iterator = length;

        // Perform a Reversed Linear Search
        if (iterationStopCount == 1)
             while (iterator) if (array[iterator -= 1] == element) return true;

        // Perform what I call a "Gradient Search"
        else {
            /*
                This condition is here because I do not know
                the algorithm behaves otherwise.
            */
            if (iterationStopCount > length) iterationStopCount = length;

            bool hasRedundantIterations = length % iterationStopCount;
            int* iterationStops = step(length, iterationStopCount),
                iterationStopsLength = iterationStopCount;

            build(iterationStops, [](int step) { return step >> 0; });

            iterator -= iterationStops[1];
            iterationStops[0] = 0;

            if (iterator != -1)
            while (iterator) {
                int iterationStopsIterator = iterationStopsLength;

                iterator -= 1;

                while (iterationStopsIterator)
                if (array[iterator + iterationStops[iterationStopsIterator -= 1]] == element)
                    return true;
            }
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

This method is exactly like the first code earlier, but indexes `iterationStopCount` elements at a time every iteration (From prior testing I found `iterationStopCount = 4` to be the most performant).

Now, to address the elephant in this code.

Yes, the `hasRedundantIndexes` variable states that this algorithm can perform redundant checks (query an array index multiple times (twice at maximum)), but this only happens if the `iterationStopCount` is not a factor of the `length` of the array.

---

I call this method of searching arrays a **Gradient Search** because it:

- Splits the array at various stops (indexes) and
- Linear searches every stop's range each iteration (which has been
  reduced to avoid inaccuracy/ redundancy).

**What I've done here could be (or is, I don't know) slower than Linear Searching or Binary Searching for ordered lists** but I see it has merit because:

- It does not need the list to be ordered.
- It spends less time than the slowest speed of a Linear Search (e.g.: \$O(n)\$) since each iteration covers a broad scope of the array.

I would say it falls short for basic searches through minimal-sized arrays.

---

I want to now hand this to you: Does this **method** (what I called an algorithm) really have any advantage or utility?

If the **method** is efficient in its field, then I will use it further on for my personal projects; else I'll debunk it myself and forget about it.

Comment: Without trying to understand what your method does, let me just state that theoretically, you cannot beat a linear scan. Indeed, there is a linear lower bound for the problem and a matching upper bound is exhibited by a linear scan. Moreover, even in practice, scanning an array in a linear fashion is natural for modern hardware and thus very fast.

Comment: this is tagged as both [tag:c] and [tag:c++]. Please pick one. They are different languages with different features and different idioms.